# JFET circuit solving

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, resistors, power-electronics

[image]
I want to find out the value of R2, R3, R4, R5. How can I solve it? anyone can help me?

For JFET1 VGS=0v, VDS = 15v.
For JFET2 VGS=1v, VDS = 18v.

[image]

Comment: Use a simulator.

Comment: I want to know solving process

Comment: Well both JFETs will be turned on with those GS voltages. Think again because N channel JFETs require a negative voltage on the gate with respect to source to allow it to be controlled in linear circuits. Also mark which JFET1 and 2 are on the schematic. It may be obvious after a few minutes which is which but 100 people reading this is wasting a lot of accumulated time.

Comment: You should have been taught the solving process, otherwise it would be cruel to ask you to solve this. In its current form the question doesn't even seem answerable/solvable as there are no parameters given for the JFETs.

Comment: Jfet with "Vgs = 1V"? Some mistake surely, unless it's something a lot more exotic than silicon...

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a big tip.
Use this diagram to solve for all the unknown resistors values:

[image]